# Anaconda: matplotlib PdfPages import error

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, attributeerror, pdfpages

I've a problem with importing the PdfPages function from the matplotlib package on my anaconda environment. I get the following error:

```
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/hpc/capn/mppi033h/.virtualenv/h5_to_histo_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 32, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backend_bases import (RendererBase, GraphicsContextBase,
  File "/home/hpc/capn/mppi033h/.virtualenv/h5_to_histo_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 63, in <module>
    import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
  File "/home/hpc/capn/mppi033h/.virtualenv/h5_to_histo_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 17, in <module>
    import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
  File "/home/hpc/capn/mppi033h/.virtualenv/h5_to_histo_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1439, in <module>
    _rebuild()
  File "/home/hpc/capn/mppi033h/.virtualenv/h5_to_histo_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py", line 1421, in _rebuild
    with cbook.Locked(cachedir):
  File "/home/hpc/capn/mppi033h/.virtualenv/h5_to_histo_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 2738, in __enter__
    files = glob.glob(self.pattern)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'glob'
```

Importing matplotlib (import matplotlib) works fine though. I'm running python in a virtual environment created with Anaconda (/.../.virtualenv/h5_to_histo_env/)

According to conda-V my version is 'conda 4.3.16' and my matplotlib version is 2.0.2 ('np112py27_0'). 
My Anaconda environment is up to date as well, does anybody know why I get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Reinstalling the virtual anaconda environment and specifying the needed packages at the beginning with the conda create command (and not after the virtual env is already created) fixed it somehow!

Comment: Actually the error seems to be due to a conflict of the virtualenv matplotlib and the system matplotlib. 
If I mistakenly import matplotlib and PdfPages with the system-mpl, I get a warning that mpl is building the font-cache. If I then activate the virtualenv and do the same thing with the virtualenv-mpl, I get an error thrown. The solution then is to exit the env again and import PdfPages in the system-mpl once. After that, I can import the virtualenv-PdfPages again fine. So it seems to be a conflict of the system and the virtualenv mpl.